# git: How to get copies of conflicting files?

Tags: git, bash

When executing a `git fetch` or `get pull` there might be a conflict. Is there a way to get copies of all conflicting files? For example file `foo.dat` is in conflict, then I would like to have copies `foo.dat.ours` and `foo.dat.theirs`. I think SVN has a similar behaviour.

1. Get conflicting filenames `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U`
2. Foreach make a copy with `.ours` postfix (`xargs cp`)
3. Get their copy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Git SCM book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging), under "Manual File Re-merging" we see:

> Git stores all of these versions in the index under “stages” which each have numbers associated with them. Stage 1 is the common ancestor, stage 2 is your version and stage 3 is from the MERGE_HEAD, the version you’re merging in (“theirs”).

From that, here's an approximate bash script approach:

```
for file in $(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U); do
  git show ":1:${file}" > "${file}".common
  git show ":2:${file}" > "${file}".ours
  git show ":3:${file}" > "${file}".theirs
done
```